# Calculation in Gridview Itemtemplate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have two itemTemplate in Gridview, need to perform multiplication operation and store it in another column, How would i do that? i.e multiply `productPrice` and `productQuantity` and store in `totalPrice` label. Thank You

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AutopartConnectionString %>" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT [id], [productID], [productName], [productPrice], [productQuantity], [totalPrice] FROM [cartDetails]"
     UpdateCommand="UPDATE [cartDetails] SET [productQuantity]=@productQuantity WHERE [productID]=@productID"
     DeleteCommand="DELETE [cartDetails] WHERE [productID]=@productID">
        <%--<UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="productQuantity" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="productQuantity" Type="String" />
       </UpdateParameters>--%>
        <DeleteParameters>
             <asp:Parameter Name="productID" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="id" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="id" Visible="False">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="productID" SortExpression="productID" >

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("productID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="productName" SortExpression="productName">

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("productName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="productPrice" SortExpression="productPrice">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("productPrice") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="productQuantity" SortExpression="productQuantity">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("productQuantity") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("productQuantity") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="totalPrice" SortExpression="totalPrice">

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# ((Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("productPrice")))*(Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("productQuantity")))).ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
                   <%-- <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("totalPrice") %>'></asp:Label>--%>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

My Table structure

```
Create table cartDetails(
id int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
productID int not null,
productName VARCHAR(150) not null ,
productPrice float,
productQuantity int,
totalPrice float
);
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code? Do you see something in `totalPrice`?

Comment: @ConnorsFan I get this  `Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'Bind' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: OK. So, even without the calculation column, you must have some problems. You can replace `Bind` with `Eval` in all columns.

Comment: Oh Ok no problem ! I am getting this error when running `Must declare the scalar variable "@productQuantity" `

Comment: @ConnorsFan I changed it to Eval and it worked fine but update and delete commands doesn't work now. I am a newbie and its really confusing

Comment: This article (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx) seems to suggest that `Bind` should be used in `EditItemTemplate` and `InsertItemTemplate`. My prior advice to use `Eval` everywhere may have been wrong in those cases.

Comment: Look at your commands. For every @parameter there needs to be a parameter of the corresponding type (select, update, delete)

Comment: @mason I fixed that , but its not updating or deleting

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason for not doing the math in the `Select`? or you can even make totalPrice a computed field in the table designer.

```
SELECT [id]
    ,  [productID]
    ,  [productName]
    ,  [productPrice]
    ,  [productQuantity]
    ,  [productPrice] * [productQuantity] as [totalPrice] 
    FROM [cartDetails]
```

and then just bind `totalPrice`

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("totalPrice") %>'</asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Also, regarding math within an `ItemTemplate`; you must use Eval() and you must make sure there are no null values.  Judicious use of `isnull(<field>,0)` in the `SELECT` statement as needed.